How to store an image in MySQL via the command-line interface?
I am having trouble stuffing a small image into a MySQL table, from a bash shell script.
Please, no "You shouldn't do that" lectures. I'm just storing small thumbnails, and also storing a path to the big image. I've stored images in databases before from PHP, but I'm able to re-use a lot of existing code before this snippet, so I'd prefer to do it from the MySQL CLI, if I possibly can.
Here's the code snippet that isn't working:
…
# Store a thumbnail of the image file, together with path and image name.

tmp="/tmp/$1"
/usr/local/bin/magick \
    "$1" \
    -thumbnail 256x256 \
    -unsharp 1.5x1+0.7+0.02 \
    ${tmp}
thumb=`cat $tmp`
fullpath=`realpath $1`
dirpath=`dirname "${fullpath}"`
basename=`basename "${fullpath}"`
sql="INSERT INTO Bird_Images SET \
    \`Master_Guide\` = \"${handle}\", \
    \`Thumb\` = \"${thumb}\" \
    \`Path\` = \"${dirpath}\", \
    \`Filename\` = \"${basename}\""
echo $fullpath
echo $dirpath
echo $basename
#echo $sql

/usr/local/bin/mysql \
    --user=GPS_User \
    --password=ReSu_SpG \
    --host=localhost \
    --database=Personal \
    --execute="${sql}"

When I run this, the diagnostic echos have the right contents. The $tmp file is only 45,164 bytes. I can manually store that image file into the proper field using a GUI database tool (Sequel Pro, Querius).
If I delete the image field from the SQL, the other fields get stored properly, so it isn't a syntax error.
I get the same results if I use a $tmp file or if I output the image into a variable and feed that to mysql.
ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\l'.


This produces the same error if I use bash to manually stuff the image in a variable and feed it to mysql manually. The variable is quoted in my script, so I can only assume there was another quote in the image data that broke things. I can't protect it with "strong" single quotes without the variable being interpreted as a literal string.
Any ideas? Because my next idea is to re-write the whole thing in a proper programming language, which I'd rather not do at this point! (There's a bunch of working code before this that would be difficult to re-code that I don't want to re-write!)
Thanks in advance for any advice offered!

Does this answer your question? storing binary data in mysql

Thank you for that suggestion. I tried LOAD_FILE() early on, and could not get it to work. I've been playing with it for the past couple hours, and still can't get it to work. I have proper permissions, I have FILE privilege, I even edited my.cnf—>secure-file-priv=/tmp/ and re-started the whole computer — still says LOAD_FILE() returned NULL. AAARRRGGGHHH!!!

@BerndBuffen GOT IT! Thanks to you. The user I'm doing this under did not have FILE privilege! If you write this as an answer, I'll up-vote it and mark it solved! Thanks again for steering me in the right path!
